# grub says unknown file system. what do I do?

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I have a dual boot PC with Windows XP and Lubuntu.

What happened is, I tried to uninstall Lubuntu by trying to format the root drive while using Lubuntu. it  just said error, so I looked for other ways to uninstall Lubuntu.

I got what I wanted, but when I restarted, I got:

```
error:unknown file system.
grub rescue>
```

I tried ls, and got all those hard drive partitions, but none has the root directory.

What do I do?

Comment: Take a look at [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 0):

Boot with a LiveCD of your distro.

Open a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Open the boot-repair window

Select the first option and wait until the process finishes.

Restart your computer without the LiveCD

If the problem is not solved. Then, boot again with the LiveCD in the terminal execute

```
gksu boot-repair
```

Select the second choice and wait until it finishes.

Restart.

Visit the official help page for Boot-repair. They provide a more detailed step-by-step, with screenshots and everything. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair