# grub recovery after partition deleted

Tags: grub2

So after getting an error when trying to update my Ubuntu partition I decided to delete it and start over.  Did it from windows and now I can't boot into either.  Did some research and every thing I found requires me to boot from a cd or flash drive but it wont recognize the disc. Went into the bios to make it boot from cd and still wont work

Comment: For your CD is not working; don't you think you need to make new one, may be that one is too old & re-used many times already. The best way is burn an ISO on a USB/Flash drive. For that : [How to create a bootable USB
stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), [How to create a bootable USB stick
on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu). Hope you know rest of the process. OR [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Comment: So using boot repair disk on a flash drive I can get it to boot, its a start.  Now I need to install grub since it and all of my ubuntu files were deleted, how do I go about doing that?  I've found plenty of guides on REinstalling it that require me to mount the linux partition that I no longer have, what do I have to do different?

Comment: Do you have Windows partition in healthy condition?? If yes then go to : [How to fix the MBR for Windows 7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7) OR [How to Remove Linux Boot Loader from Startup After Deleting Linux Partitions?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-linux-boot-loader-from-startup-after-deleting-linux-partition-on-a-dual-boot-system/); second option is best as you no longer using UBUNTU. Hope this will help you. Marry Xmas.

Answer (score 0):

To boot from live disk: the best way is to burn an ISO on a USB/Flash drive.
For Windows : [How to create a bootable USB stick on **Windows**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
For UBUNTU : [How to create a bootable USB stick on **Ubuntu**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).
To restore GRUB : [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

Now, If your Windows Partition is in healthy Condition then go to : [How to fix the MBR for Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7) to restore GRUB from UBUNTU
OR [How to Remove Linux Boot Loader from Startup After Deleting Linux Partitions?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-remove-linux-boot-loader-from-startup-after-deleting-linux-partition-on-a-dual-boot-system/) to do it from Windows. I think this second option is best as you no longer using UBUNTU. For this second option you'll need Windows' bootable disc.
If your windows installation is corrupt then after restoring Boot loader entry in to MBR, try to repair your Windows.

Hope this will help you.