# Deleted Ubuntu prtition from machine and going back to Win - can't get past "grub rescue" on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grubrescue

I wanted to go back to an all Windows machine after trying Ubuntu 15.04. It was a good experiment, but not for me.

I had installed Ubuntu 15.04 on its own partition and it put in a dual boot menu. At start-up I chose either Ubuntu or Win 7.

After making the decision to delete Ubuntu, I went into the Disk Manager in Windows and used the Delete Volume command to free up the space. That left me with all free space where I had Ubuntu.

When I rebooted thinking I would go straight to windows, I get the "grub rescue >" command and can't figure out what to do to get back into Windows.

I have read several of the other fixes in this forum, but they all seem to be aimed at recovering the Ubuntu partition and not to getting past the rescue screen and back to Windows.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, an insight to your problem: the default installation of Ubuntu would set the boot loader to the Ubuntu partition grub. When you delete the partition you have deleted the boot code along with it.

Solution: Repair Windows loader and set it as the boot loader. I suppose you could try @pischkot suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, the topic below may answer it. Boot  via Ubuntu Live disc/USB and use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

[How to fix the MBR for Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7)

Option 2; [EasyRE Recovery USB](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/tips-and-tricks/easyre-recovery-usb/)

Option 3; You can use this link
https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/