# How to dual boot with two drives

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

My laptop came with Windows 8 on one drive and I installed a MSATA drive and installed Ubuntu on that. The installer setup a selection in grub for windows but when selected it goes to the following screen:

[image: Windows failiied to start. A recent hardware of software change might be the cause To fix the problem....]

I have seen several other posts with the same issue but they all seem to be how to accomplish this during the install. Since the install is complete at this point how can I correct it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjZy8.png

Comment: do u have ubuntu bootable usb/dvd ??

Comment: I **suspect** that the windows boot part if looking for a path on the first drive. With the mSATA drive added that now has become the second drive. Which means that you need to edit the BCDstore

Comment: I've had this problem before with GRUB and I'm pretty sure it happens because GRUB detects Windows as a legacy boot, when it's actually an EFI install. Have you run `sudo update-grub` yet?

Comment: BIOS is calling the MSATA HDD2 and the drive with windows HDD0, Im guessing thats the issue do I just need change the device line in BCDstore from partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2 to partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume0?

Comment: Did you leave Windows fast start up on which is always on hibernation? That always causes issues. If UEFI you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu or one time boot key, often f10 or f12 check manual. And then maybe f8 to get into Windows internal repair console.  If BIOS you just about need your Windows repair flash drive. Grub only boots working Windows, and Windows does need repair sometimes. Post the link from Boot-Repair for the Summary Report to show how you have installed and other details.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Windows DVD & go to boot menu & boot DVD. On Install page click on `Repair`. If this is successfully done, then insert Ubuntu bootable media (USB/DVD) & boot from it. Select `Try Ubuntu`. Then open `terminal` &  type these commands.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install boot-repair`

Now, Press `Windows Key` type `Boot Repair`.

Click on `Recommended Repair`

Restart & check you should get dual boot option.

Comment: any work around if I dont have the windows dvd?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7 check this out.